# Fill in gaps in QGIS shapes?

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, attribute-joins, dissolve

So basically, I've written a script that generates a lot of polygons over the UK with certain criteria. The output it a lot of shapes like the following - I wanted to know if, in QGIS, I'm able to join shapes like this together and fill in the holes by making a big polygon over the whole thing.

[image: ?]

Comment: The `minimum bounding geometry` or `concave hull` tool might do it.

Comment: Or make a giant polygon that covers more than the entire area. Intersect that polygon with the ones you have here. That will leave one large ring polygon outside the area boundary. Select and delete that polygon, then dissolve the remaining polygons.

Comment: In QGIS there is also a possibility of using `"Fill holes"` but it will only work for *interior* holes, for *exterior* gaps, I would suggest tackling the way offered by @csk